# How do i push to the git-repo of Scriptler?

Tags: git, jenkins, tortoisegit, jenkins-scriptler

From https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin

> Git Scriptler exposes its scripts via git. Browse to
>   JENKINS_URL/scriptler.git on your installation to get more info about
>   how to access the repo via git.
>
> This allows an administrator to push/pull scripts from its
>   workstation/IDE into Scriptler. If such a script is pushed the first
>   time into scriptler, then it will parse the optional header info like
>   this:

I have the scriptler-plugin on my jenkins and want to push changes to it. Cloning/Pulling works even anonymously.

I have configured my username in git, but the server responeded error 403, that a push as anonymous is not allowed.
I'm trying to push over http.

My jenkins runs on windows and i havent configured any ssh-software explicit.
My own computer is windows too and i have the git client installed. Additionally tortoise-git.

I dont know what i'm doing wrong. How i have to communicate my username and password?

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out myself:

- Make sure that your user has a public SSH key assigned (see https://jenkins.server/jenkins/user/username/configure )
- Make sure that your local ssh installation has the corresponding private key for the public key (cf. ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
- Don't use https, but use the ssh protocol for your git repo to push (cf. ssh://jenkins.server:34841/scriptler.git)

Then, you are able to push the changes as usual

(if checked out before)

`git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/master`

*(or if pushing from some other repository)*

`git push ssh://jenkins.server:34841/scriptler.git HEAD:refs/heads/master`

Comment: I don't get it working :-(
Even cloning doesn't work via ssh.
I have a ppk-file and extracted with PuttyGen (Conversions > Export OpenSSH key) the puplic key into a id_rsa-file.
That file is located within "c:\Program Files\Git\.ssh\" (Got that from here: http://serverfault.com/a/198691)
TortoiseGit and the ppk-file don't work too.
Because id_rsa looks different than ppk i'm not sure what and how to use.

Comment: What confuses me additionally is the port 34841. The scriptler-page mentions 57159.

Comment: @Simn, I bet that scriptler picks a random port to use

Comment: This helped. Note that SSH server must be enabled in Jenkins configuration (Security section) for this to work, thus consider security implications.